# how to get password as submitted by the user in hook_user_insert?

Tags: hooks, users

I have extended the core using hook_user_insert. but when i print the $edit argument inside the function i get password fields as encrypted.

Is there any way i can get the non-encrypted value of password as submitted by the user.

I am using drupal 7

Following is the $edit array

```
Array
(
    [uid] => 28
    [hostname] => 127.0.0.1
    [roles] => Array
        (
            [2] => authenticated user
        )

    [cache] => 0
    [administer_users] => 
    [name] => raul1
    [mail] => raul1@tst.com
    [pass] => $S$DskyNMYOrdQoEdErlYPN701I1jSBBrzetjSjb2XPzlooVcfcp8Rp
    [status] => 
    [notify] => 0
    [timezone] => Asia/Kolkata
    [signature] => 
    [picture] => 
    [picture_delete] => 0
    [picture_upload] => 
    [signature_format] => filtered_html
    [init] => raul1@tst.com
    [field_first_name] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => Raul
                        )

                )

        )

    [field_last_name] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => Garcia
                        )

                )

        )

    [is_new] => 1
    [created] => 1356067366
    [theme] => 
    [access] => 0
    [login] => 0
    [language] => 
)
```

is there any tweaking to get the user submitted password from D7 registration form?

I know its impossible to get back the hashed value. or how to find out the salt associated with each hashed password

Comment: Best you can do IMO is build your own external authentication module against your ERP backend (which hopefully also uses hashes and salt to store users passwords).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any hook that is invoked from [user_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_save/7) is too late to get the password as entered from the user. In fact, the first lines executed from `user_save()` are the following ones.

```php
$transaction = db_transaction();
try {
  if (isset($edit['pass']) && strlen(trim($edit['pass'])) > 0) {
    // Allow alternate password hashing schemes.
    require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . variable_get('password_inc', 'includes/password.inc');
    $edit['pass'] = user_hash_password(trim($edit['pass']));

    // Abort if the hashing failed and returned FALSE.
    if (!$edit['pass']) {
      return FALSE;
    }
  }

  // …
}
```

What you can do is adding a form submission handler to the form used to create new user accounts. That submission handler can access the password as entered from the user in `$form_state['values']['pass']`. I would rather add a form submission handler that is executed right after [`user_register_submit()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_register_submit/7), as that submission handler contains the following code.

if (!variable_get('user_email_verification', TRUE) || $admin) {
$pass = $form_state['values']['pass'];
}
else {
$pass = user_password();
}
$notify = !empty($form_state['values']['notify']);

// Remove unneeded values.
form_state_values_clean($form_state);

$form_state['values']['pass'] = $pass;

````
I would use the following code.

```php
function mymodule_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // Add your submission handler.
  $form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_user_register_submit';
}

function mymodule_user_register_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // The password is in $form_state['values']['pass'].
}
````

Comment: my biggest problem is i only have a weeks experience in drupal.so i don't actually understand what is a submission handler.i guess it is done using hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id). and how to execute the code inside this hook after  user_register_submit() ?

Comment: I followed the way u said, but its not entering the function mymodule_form_user_register_form_alter. replace mymodule with my custom module name

Comment: hook_form_alter is working after i cleared the cache,but after submitting it is not going to the function mymodule_user_register_submit.what am i doing wrong?I have already defined hook_user_insert.so it is going to this function

Comment: inside mymodule_user_register_submit. is this function executed after the data is inserted to the db or before?please help

Comment: `mymodule_user_register_submit()` is called after `user_save()`, so the user data are already saved in the database.

Comment: ok, so my guess was correct, we cannot manipulate the data before it is being inserted. so i wrote function to take $form_state['values'] as argument and did my coding there.It works now, Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: You could execute `mymodule_user_register_submit()` before `user_register_submit()`; in that way, `mymodule_user_register_submit()` would be executed before `user_save()`. You would need to duplicate the code I shown in the second snippet. You should also use `array_unshift($form['#submit'], 'mymodule_user_register_submit');` instead of `$form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_user_register_submit';`.

Comment: i tried as you said.But now user_save() is not executing. how to execute it?