# Execute user_save() after the form submission handler

Tags: users

In my implementation of `hook_form_alter()` I am using the following code; it executes `mymodule_user_form_submit()` before `user_save()`.

```
array_unshift($form['#submit'], 'mymodule_user_form_submit');
```

`user_save()` is not executing after that.

What is the problem with this code?

I want to execute `user_save()` after `mymodule_user_form_submit()`.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
    drupal_set_message("Form ID is : " . $form_id);
    //$form['#submit'][] = 'custom_user_form_submit';
    array_unshift($form['#submit'], 'mymodule_user_register_submit');
  }

}

function mymodule_user_register_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
//code goes here
$form_state['field_magentopass']['und'][0]['value'] = $form_state['values']['pass'];
}
```

if the code is wrong how can i assign the value to this variable `$form_state['field_magentopass']['und'][0]['value']`

or this entire method is wrong?
should i go for any other alternatives?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Drupal Answers. To which form are you attaching your submission handler? How do you know `user_save()` is not executed?

Comment: Also, may you show the code you are using?

Comment: @kiamlaluno: i have added the code in question.It is actually a follow up of this thread [link]http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53855/how-to-get-password-as-submitted-by-the-user-in-hook-user-insert[/link]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, your submit handler ( `mymodule_user_register_submit` ) and actual function name ( `custom_user_form_submit` ) are different.

Also, your submit handler is using

```
$form_state['field_magentopass']
```

instead of

```
$form_state['values']['field_magentopass']...
```

It should be something like

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter
 * User register form id: user_register_form
 */
function mymodule_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  drupal_set_message("Form ID is : " . $form_id);
  array_unshift($form['#submit'], 'mymodule_user_register_submit');

}

function mymodule_user_register_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['values']['field_magentopass'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $form_state['values']['pass'];
}
```

UPDATE: OP changed their question to use matching function names. Apparently new $user is saved, but field_magentopass wasn't updated.

Lastly, an alternative approach, based on form_set_value and the #validate handler

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter
 * User register form id: user_register_form
 */
function mymodule_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  drupal_set_message("Form ID is : " . $form_id);
  $form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_user_register_validate';

}

function mymodule_user_register_validate($form, &$form_state){
  $form['field_magentopass']['#parents'] = array('field_magentopass'); 
  form_set_value($form['field_magentopass'], array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(0 => array('value' => $form_state['values']['pass']))), $form_state);
}
```

Comment: sorry its a typo.i corrected it now

Comment: OK, what is the code in your submit handler? If that fails, the rest of the code will fail to run.

Comment: I have a field in registration from which is hidden,and i want to assign the user submitted password from form to that variable so that it stores in table field_data_field_magentopass in drupal database

Comment: Any error messages in logs?

Comment: no errors. it creates a drupal user. but it will not insert data to the table field_data_field_magentopass

Comment: What about the adjusted snippet I posted in my answer above?  `$form_state['values']['field_magentopass'] = $form_state['values']['pass'];` any difference then?

Comment: @zamil OK, updated snippet posted, should be good to go.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7000/discussion-between-zamil-and-david-thomas)

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score -1):

You have to generate an user object in your submit function.
pass this object in user_save within same function only.

Comment: can u make it a bit more clear