# Using Authentication API module

Tags: 7, authentication-authorization

I'm trying to use the [User Authentication API](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_auth_api) module. My goal is to add some post-processing after successful Drupal 7 login that posts JSON to an external web service. This would be work very similar to the [Webform Remote Post](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_remote_post) module, but for the login page.

My problem is that even though the module is installed fine, and things look good on the page which displays detected plugins, nothing seems to fire at login. What do I need to add to see this plugin framework interact with a user login event?

This screenshot shows I have all the pieces in place.

> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The *User Authentication API* only provides an API. It doesn't provide any authentication class that can be used to really authenticate users.

What the screenshot in the question shows are [the classes used by the tests implemented by the module](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/user_auth_api/-/tree/7.x-1.x/tests/user_auth_api_test/plugins), whose purpose is only testing the module works correctly.

You need to find a module that uses the *User Authentication API* module, or a totally different module, that doesn't what you trying to do.

Comment: Drupal does a fine job of authenticating people already. I merely want to intercept the login/pass, encrypt it, and send it off to an ASP.net webservice so that when users authenticate in Drupal, they simultaneously authenticate elsewhere. Is that not what this module attempts to help me with?

Comment: It helps writing a module for authenticating users, but it doesn't send data to an external server after users are authenticated, as that is behind authenticating users.

Comment: If it will help me get the non-encrypted value of the password as submitted by the user, I can handle the rest. My sites/all/custom/module (containing the test plugins) is detected, how do I see some indication in watchdog (or anywhere) upon user login.

Comment: I need to grab the unhashed password at login. Looks like you've helped people grab the password during registration here... https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53855/how-to-get-password-as-submitted-by-the-user-in-hook-user-insert